# What's a good water system for my cactus plant during holidays?

Tags: watering, houseplants, cactus

I have a very resilient cactus that can be left alone for a month without consequences.

Now, I want to leave it alone during two months and leave it some water system.

I have seen little earthen jars that can be put into the pot and filled with water.

Does this work? How big should they be?

Is there another system that works?

Comment: [Related](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/28/growing-chili-in-a-dorm-room)

Comment: If it's something that really needs very little looking after, couldn't you leave it with a friend or have a friend stop by once or twice?  That seems far simpler than buying or rigging up an automated system for one plant for one trip.

Answer (score 9):

You do not say where you live. Since it is a cactus, here is what I would do. I would not place it in a situation where it stands in water. That would kill it because the roots do not like siting in water. If it is not going to be cold I would put it outside in a shady area. The natural moisture (morning dew or rain) would be sufficient to keep it alive and happy for two months or longer. I have mine in full sun to shade and rarely water.

Answer (score 6):

The porous clay watering systems that I've seen include an attachment that you use for a drinking bottle to automatically fill, so I'm not positive these are the same that you're referring to.  However, this will release quite a bit of water for a cactus and wouldn't last for 2 months (mine is usually empty after a week, so my fast drinking plant can last about 2 weeks without me).

A simple DIY solution is to place one container of water above the plant and leave a piece of string or fabric running from the container down to the cactus.  The string will slowly wick the water down.

There are also electronic systems that may give you more control, though they are expensive (e.g. [this one over on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000U5YFR4).

No matter which solution you use, test it long before you leave so you can be sure there are no leaks, and should it over waters things, you're around to stop it.