# Can someone identify this plant with a strangely shaped leaf?

Tags: identification

[image]

If someone could give me the name of this plant, I would be very grateful. Even a common name would do.

The guy I bought it from does not know the name, but I know that it can only have two leaves at a time. I tried searching on a lot of websites but couldn't identify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plant is Amazon elephant's ear ([Alocasia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alocasia) amazonica).  It is a tropical plant that does not withstand cold temperatures and prefers to be in moist or wet soil.  Provide bright but not direct sun and keep in high humidity if possible.

This plant would be a good candidate for a self watering system using a wick and water reservoir as described [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4280/non-mechanical-plant-watering-systems).

Answer (score 4):

Specifically it is Alocasia Polly.  Its a great houseplant and it can have more than two leaves at once.  Lots of images on the web of this plant.  [Here is just one of many](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/showimage/60423/#b)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it is an Alocasia, though from my watch its Alocasia mortfontanensis.