# Watering while away from home

Tags: watering

Most of my plants die when I am away for a week or 2 weeks. Is there any way to water them regularly?

I don't have a water tap on my balcony. And if I move plants inside they die because of a lack of sunlight.

Comment: See also: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4280/non-mechanical-plant-watering-systems/

Comment: And: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/28/51

Comment: Thanks, I dint find them in search and suggestions before raising the question.

Comment: No problem. If you find some issue that is not answered in those posts, feel free to post another question.